# $(document).ready equivalent in asynchronously loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a UI (let's call it **page 1**) which has a lot of HTML and JavaScript in it. When some of the elements on page 1 are clicked, a jQuery UI Dialog is opened and loaded with a partial page (let's call that **page 2**):

```js
$("#myDialog").dialog({ modal: true /* Other options */ });
$('#myDialog').load('page2Link', { }, function () { });
$('#myDialog').dialog('open');
```

Page 2 then has a bunch of HTML and JavaScript as well. Simplified example:

```html
<script src="Scripts/page2Stuff.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="page2Body">
    <!-- More elements -->
</div>
```

I have JS inside `page2Stuff.js` that needs to wait until page 2 is completely rendered. Is there something I can use within this partial page to see if the new HTML has been added to the DOM? I have tried the following:

```js
$('#myDialog').load('page2Link', { }, page2ReadyFunction);
```

This can't find `page2ReadyFunction`. I assume because `.load` runs the JavaScript in `page2Stuff.js` and then discards it or something?

The way I'm able to get it to work now it to use `setTimeout` and continually check to see if `$('#page2Body')` returns anything but this doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: page2ReadyFunction would be a callback handler called upon completion of the load. that would be the best way to go, don't know why it's not getting called? can you explain how you implemented/defined page2ReadyFunction ?

Comment: Why don't you simply put the `script` at the end of `page2`?

Comment: @c4urself page2ReadyFunction would just be a function defined in the page2Stuff.js like so: function page2ReadyFunction() { }

Comment: @Joseph Silber does that guarantee that the page has been rendered by the time it gets to the script tag?

Comment: @xbrady - Sure. The HTML is processed by source order. If the last thing is the `script`, everything before that would have loaded.

Comment: @JosephSilber: +1. Please post your answer as such, so it can be voted on and/or accepted. :-)

Comment: The JavaScript should load after the rendering event regardless of where it is placed in the child document.  `jQuery.fn.load` uses AJAX to load the HTML and then injects it into the node.  As such, the script tag should execute asynchronously **after** the node insertion completes.

Comment: @BrianNickel - That's only true if it would be one node. Being that they're 2 separate ones, they'll be loaded according to source order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having your `script` tag at the beginning of your second page, put it at the end of it, after all the HTML, like this:

```
<div id="page2Body">
    <!-- More elements -->
</div>

<script src="Scripts/page2Stuff.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Since the code will be executed according to source order, you can rest assured that the HTML will be ready by the time your script runs.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the `load` function, it is expecting `page2ReadyFunction` to exist at that exact time.  It does not because you haven't loaded the script.  The following would get around that problem but also *shouldn't* work because the script will load asynchronously:

```
$('#myDialog').load('page2Link', { }, function() {page2ReadyFunction();});
```

To get around that problem, you could do something like this:

```
$('#myDialog').load('page2Link', { }, function() {
    function tryPageLoad() {
        if(page2ReadyFunction)
            page2ReadyFunction();
        else
            setTimeout(tryPageLoad, 100);
    }
    tryPageLoad();
});
```

This function tries every 100ms to see if `page2ReadyFunction` exists and calls it when it does.

Of course, you shouldn't have to worry about any of this because the child script tag will load asynchronously and the rendering should happen before the JavaScript executes.  You could verify this by using `console.log` to see what fires first, the JavaScript in the client script or the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

the callback function for load from the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

> complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)A callback function
>   that is executed when the request completes.

This function executes when the request completes, but you need to wait until page2 has been rendered.

A simple solution would be to put a $(document).ready() block into the javascript files that page2 pulls.

Comment: This won't work because the elements in page to are being loaded into the document for page1. $(document).ready() in page2 will immediately run since the document is already ready. right?

Answer (score 0):

please if you want something to load after complete ajax load

you gotta use the

full ajax function like that

```
var req= $.ajax({
            url:'page2Link',
            type:"post",
            data:{ajax:1,field_id:field_ids,whatever:whatever}

        }); 
        //after loading
        req.complete(function(res){
            $('#myDialog').html(res);
        });
        //after complete loading and request end
        req.always(function(res){
            page2ReadyFunction
        });
```

all that instead of

```
$('#myDialog').load('page2Link', { }, function () { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Serve out Page 2 like this:

```
<script src="Scripts/page2Stuff.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="page2Body">
    <!-- More elements -->
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    // call your function from page2Stuff.js here
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

could you use something like this:

```
<body onload="function2kickOffP2()">
```

This would go on the body of page2.